# How to hide a row if a column's value is 0 - using C#(WPF),SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am doing a project that let the students add books. And for these books there is quantity that shows how much quantity do the library have of a selected book. So my question is that When Book quantity have (0) value I want the book to be hidden from the dataGridView so student can't see it.

How do hide the row of the book that has 0 value?

C#, WPF, SQL

Best Regards

Omar Dak Elbab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple `where`:

```
select * from bookstable
where quantity <> 0
```

use this query as your datasource in datagrid

Comment: @OmarDakelbab , what do you mean!use this query as your datasource in datagrid and this query won't return list of books with 0 quantity

Comment: Yea Yea it worked Thank man i appreciate it :)

Comment: i have another question can you help me

Comment: @OmarDakelbab post a new question then , thanks

Comment: i want to limit the maximum books that student can take am i gonna use max count

Comment: @OmarDakelbab please post anew question with sample data and desired output ,